# How to create a new column showing the difference between 2 time columns (start and end time) using Presto?

Tags: sql, datetime, presto, calculated-columns, trino

Hello Stackoverflow community. New analyst here with a few questions.

My goal is to create a new column in a query to show the difference between start_time and end_time displayed as minutes.

The start_time and end_time columns are currently in varchar format (e.g. 6:30 PM or 4:00 AM). I'd like to convert these 2 columns into a 24H format then create a new column which subtracts end_time - start_time to display a new column (meeting_duration).

I'm currently using Presto.

My initial thought was to convert varchar into time and then create a column which subtracts the two fields. However, that's easier said than done. I continue running into errors (my SQL is very basic). I'm new to the field and have been having trouble. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You don't have date in your sample. So you never have rows that span more than one day? Like Start 11:50 PM Sunday, End 2:30 AM Monday.

Comment: @Isolated That is correct. The data does not contain dates, only time. The start_time and end_time fields occur on a daily basis during normal business hours (typically 8AM-8PM).

Answer (score 0):

You could add a calculated column to your database table. Then the calculation is done automatically on insert.

```
CREATE TABLE meetings_duration_table (
  start_time varchar,
  end_time varchar,
  meeting_duration_minutes AS (TIME_DIFF(
    TIME_PARSE(start_time, '%l:%i %p'),
    TIME_PARSE(end_time, '%l:%i %p'),
    MINUTE
  ))
);
```

Or if you wanted to do it as a query, it'd be something like

```
SELECT
  start_time,
  end_time,
  TIME_DIFF(
    TIME_PARSE(end_time, '%l:%i %p'),
    TIME_PARSE(start_time, '%l:%i %p'),
    MINUTE
  ) AS meeting_duration_minutes
FROM
  meetings_table;
```

Comment: I can't find `TIME_PARSE` and `TIME_DIFF` in Presto.

Answer (score 0):

If both times are in the same day you can just parse it as date and then format in new way:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(start_time, end_time ) as (
    values ('4:00 AM', '6:30 PM')
)

-- query
select date_format(start_time, '%H:%i') start_time,
       date_format(end_time, '%H:%i') end_time,
       date_diff('minute', start_time, end_time) meeting_duration_mins
from (select date_parse(start_time, '%l:%i %p') start_time,
             date_parse(end_time, '%l:%i %p')   end_time
      from dataset);
```

Output:

| start_time | end_time | meeting_duration_mins |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 04:00 | 18:30 | 870 |

For more info about date formats check out the [Date and Time Functions and Operators](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html) doc.